# How do I iterate over all elements having a particular class and find an input type in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I "iterate" to the next `.RatedSection input`? I have to pull randomly generated IDs and then add a label for each input. How do I do this?

This code is not iterating,and it's just inserting the label for the same element 95 times.

```
function addLabel(){
    var classElements=document.querySelectorAll('.RatedSection');
    var counter;

    for(counter = 0; counter < classElements.length; counter++){
        var id=$('.RatedSection input').attr('id');
        var str;
        var idHash='#'+ id;


        if($('.RatedSection input').val()==1)
            str='<label for="'+ id + '">7</label>';

        else if($('.RatedSection input').val()==2)
            str='<label for="'+ id + '">6</label>';

        else if($('.RatedSection input').val()==3)
            str='<label for="'+ id + '">5</label>';

        else if($('.RatedSection input').val()==4)
            str='<label for="'+ id + '">4</label>';

        else if($('.RatedSection input').val()==5)
            str='<label for="'+ id + '">3</label>';

        else if($('.RatedSection input').val()==6)
            str='<label for="'+ id + '">2</label>';

        else if($('.RatedSection input').val()==7)
            str='<label for="'+ id + '">1</label>';

        else if($('.RatedSection input').val()==8)
            str='<label for="'+ id + '">NA</label>';

        $('.RatedSection '+idHash).after(str);

        console.log(str);
    }
};
```

Comment: Why are you mixing `jQuery` with `VanillaJS` ?

Comment: Does that go against convention or is there a potential error that can happen from doing this? To answer you question, I did it because I didn't think it mattered.

Comment: It does not really matter, but it creates confusion, about many things, It makes your code less readable IMO..

Comment: — Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compare your value to a proper input. You are everyitme cojmparing to the same input when you use `$('.RatedSelection input').val();` 
Using `$(this).find('input')` will enable you to refere to the current element your iterating over with a class `RatedSelection` and find an input element inside the current element.

Try it this way:

```
function addLabel(){

    $('.RatedSelection').each(function(){
      var id= $(this).find('input').attr('id');
      var str='';
      var idHash = '#' + id;
      var value = $(this).find('input').val();
      if(value==1)
            str='<label for="'+ id + '">7</label>';

        else if(value==2)
            str='<label for="'+ id + '">6</label>';

        else if(value==3)
            str='<label for="'+ id + '">5</label>';

        else if(value==4)
            str='<label for="'+ id + '">4</label>';

        else if(value==5)
            str='<label for="'+ id + '">3</label>';

        else if(value==6)
            str='<label for="'+ id + '">2</label>';

        else if(value==7)
            str='<label for="'+ id + '">1</label>';

        else if(value==8)
            str='<label for="'+ id + '">NA</label>';


        $(this).find(idHash).after(str);
    })

}
```

Comment: Most important thing, `this` context!

Comment: @Rayon what do you mean. Are you suggesting any improvement for pointing out the the goodthing about the above approach

Comment: Okay thanks, I will edit the above code. I was in a hurry for a meeting so left it to only a pure code with little explanation

Comment: Instead of using `$(this).find('input').val()` 8 times in your code, you can cache the value I mean keep it in a variable and then compare..

Answer (score 0):

Answer by [**Shubham Khatri**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5928186/shubham-khatri) is perfectly fine, but it could be done in smarter way using [***DRY***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) approach!

```js
function addLabel() {
  $('.RatedSelection').each(function() {
    var $input = $(this).find('input');
    var id = $input.attr('id');
    var idHash = '#' + id;
    var value = $input.val();
    var max = 8;
    var label = max - value;
    var str = '<label for="' + id + '">' + (label || 'NA') + '</label>';
    $(this).find(idHash).after(str);
  });
}
```